# Error writing to database in moodle

Tags: moodle

I want to customize some strings into moodle. so when i clicked on open language pack for editing it will run till 69% and thowing an error "Error writing to database"

Error/moodle/dmlwriteexception 
This indicates that a general error occurred when Moodle tried to write to the database. If you turn on Debugging you will get more detailed information about what the problem is.

MySQL 
If you're using a MySQL database for your Moodle installation, this error can be caused by the server's max_allowed_packet size being configured incorrectly. Increasing this value may resolve the issue.

I have tried to increase the value of max_allowed_packet 1M to 100M but still getting the same error.

Please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the following settings in your config.php:

```
@ini_set('display_errors', '1'); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = 32767;         // NOT FOR PRODUCTION     SERVERS! // for Moodle 2.0 - 2.2, use:  $CFG->debug = 38911;  
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;   // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```

That should tell you more about the query that is causing the error, and help resolve your problem.
When your'e done with debugging please remove these lines, since they may cause a security risk.

Source: https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Debugging#In_config.php

Answer (score 1):

Its probably a custom plugin with an incorrect string id in the language file - https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=222815

Try uninstalling any custom modules then trying again with the language customisation until you can identify which custom plugin is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if this is related, but since I received the exact same message, I', assuming so.

I am new to Moodle, and tried to install it locally on my machine. Once I was comfortable with that I migrated it to a hosted environment. I am certain I did not execute the process correctly in terms of user permissions, since as soon as I migrated the instance I started getting the "error writing to database" exception.

After a lot of research, and after trying many solutions that did not work, I eventually found something that did. It is dangerous to do this on a database that has records already written to it, however the solution was to drop the 'id' column of the effected table and add it again with auto_increment on:

Step 1: Turn on Debugging in the Page settings of your Moodle site. Any database insert will then likely return en error like this"

```html
Debug info: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
INSERT INTO mdl_course_sections (course,section,summary,summaryformat,sequence,name,visible,availability,timemodified) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
[array (
0 => '2',
1 => 10,
2 => '',
3 => '1',
4 => '',
5 => NULL,
6 => 1,
7 => NULL,
8 => 1548419949,
)] 
Error code: dmlwriteexception
```

Step 2: Since this gives you the table name and the effected field, you can then exectue the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE {table_name} DROP COLUMN {column_name};
ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN {column_name} INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
```

As there are no restrictions here, dropping a column of primary keys, which are likely foreign keys in other tables, I would not advise this unless it is a fresh install. But it worked well for me.